# photoswipe overlay button on Image

Tags: jquery, photoswipe

I am trying to overlay a button on Image in Gallery ( i.e. full screen mode in Photoswipe) and am unable to do it.

Does anyone have idea on how to do it ?

Comment: Saying you are `unable to do it` doesn't really explain what you've tried so far, or what isn't working.

Comment: I tried to overlay image by using many ways. specially css . but the settings are getting overridden. I am also able to put it button in caption bar but when I click I am not able to change it at that time. When i again load it the effect is coming

Comment: I have used     $('div.ps-caption-content').replaceWith('<button id="btn_IOS" onclick=copytext()>Play</button>');.                               By calling this once I am getting button in caption but when I call it again $('div.ps-caption-content').replaceWith('img001'); it is not working untill I reload it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess as you have already replaced it once you can't replace it again. I am talking about this.

`$('div.ps-caption-content').replaceWith('<button id="btn_IOS"  onclick=copytext()>Play</button>');`

Once you are getting button in caption you should try using something like

`$('#btn_IOS').replaceWith('#img001'); 
And I suppose here that "img001" is id of ur image control. :-)

Hope it will help you. All the best. :-)